# Notification not coming in device while not connected to xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, firebase, push-notification, ios11

I was testing my app for firebase notification in iPad Air, iPhone 6, iPhone 7
All were working fine for a couple of days. But few day ago I found that notification not coming in iPhone 6 while not connected to Xcode.

I have tried resetting certificates, removing app but not succeed.

I'd I restarted iPhone 6 than it works fine.

I don't know how this was fixed but is there any solution for this.

is there any other issue in my code??
Or there is any solution for resetting notification services from code?

please help me. I don't need restarting the phone.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Have you gotten any error messages you can share?

Comment: No. Not getting any error or warning while testing.